# How to convert OSM file ot PNG tiles on MacOS?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

Im trying to create an offline map with Leaflet. So I got this package from https://download.geofabrik.de/africa.html
Is there any way to convert osm.pbf to PNG tiles on MacOS?

Comment: The process is called "rendering" and so you can check in OSM wiki. it is complex (and slow) process (but you can style it as you want. Usually one uses services to create png. You are asking "on MacOS" so I suspect you are not asking it as a programming question, but as user, so I think you are off-topic to this site (there is one site about GIS, and one about apple products: check the links on top right icon)

Comment: Check https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering for software that runs on MacOS.

Comment: There is step by step tutorial for building tile server on Ubuntu: https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu/
I believe it can be done in a docker container if you don't have a Linux machine. The output of one of the step is PNG tiles of various zoom level.